# How to "restart" my as3 code

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got some AS3 codes on my 4th frame.

```
var words:Array = new Array; //a mini database to hold the words
var current_word:String; //used to hold the current word being tested
var ques_num:int; //used to track the question number
var tileArray:Array = new Array; //array of tile objects
var targetArray:Array = new Array; //array of target areas
var scramble_Array:Array = new Array; //array used to scramble the word

getword();

function getword() {

            words=["screen"];
            current_word=words[ques_num];
            setTiles(current_word.length);
            ques_num++;
        }//getword


         function setTiles(a) {tileArray=[ ];
            for(i=0;i<a;i++){
                var tempclip:Tile =new Tile;addChild(tempclip);
                tempclip.x=150+(i*120);tempclip.y=500;tempclip.tag=i;
                tempclip.original_posx=tempclip.x;
                tempclip.original_posy=tempclip.y;
                tileArray[i]=tempclip;

                var tempclip2:Placeholder =new Placeholder;addChild(tempclip2);
                tempclip2.x=150+(i*120);tempclip2.y=620;
                targetArray[i]=tempclip2;

            }//for i
            scramble_word(a);
        }//setTiles
```

I wanted to put a button where the user can click in order to go back to frame 1.

```
goBack1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoOne, false, 0, true);
function gotoOne(event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

When I do so, we can still see the child of the 4th frame..

So I removed them.

```
     trace("clear_board");
            removeChild(checker);
            pauser=false;
            for(i=0;i<tileArray.length;i++){
            removeChild(tileArray[i]);
            removeChild(targetArray[i]);
            }
            }
```

But now, when the user is going back to the 4th frame, an error is displayed :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at RECUPERE_jeumuseev1_fla::Jules_108/getword()[RECUPERE_jeumuseev1_fla.Jules_108::frame4:95]
```

The line 95 is this :

```
setTiles(current_word.length);
```

I suppose that the error come from the fact that I've "removed" tileArray[i] but I'm not sure..

What do you suggest I could do to simply "restart" the all code from this frame, like the first time the user is coming to the 4th code ?

Comment: Wrap this all into a **MovieClip** then just replace it in the main timeline.

Comment: not a bad idea at all ! I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: It worked ! Thx !